# errors when using htlatex

Tags: htlatex, make4ht

I'm trying to compile a .tex document into an html format, so I can convert it into a .doc file. I have enabled htlatex in MikTex, an am using windows command line by cd-ing to my directory and then entering `make4ht "name of file.tex"` This is the output in the command line:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: name of file.tex
[WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found
[WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=latex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?        Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1`
```

I have also used the command `htlatex "name of file.tex"` which gives me more errors. I should probably mention that I have no experience with htlatex, I am simply following the instructions I've found on this forum where people had other issues with htlatex. I'd be very grateful for any advise, or directions to any guide or instructions on htlatex in general, since I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: It is very hard to give suggestion unless seeing your code, please post the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Is your filename really "name of file.tex"? Have you tried removing the spaces?

Comment: as @MadyYuvi, it is really hard without seeing a minimal example that fails. Also, try the `make4ht -a debug "name of file.tex"` command. It should give you more details about the error.